# Confusion about average energy with boltzmann distribution

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, probability

When calculating the average kinetic energy of a gas, should we use
$$ <E > = \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} E_i e^{-E_i/kT}}{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}e^{-E_i/kT}}\approx \frac{\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{2}mv^2 e^{-mv^2/2kT}}{\int_0^\infty e^{-mv^2/2kT}}$$or

$$ <E > = \frac{\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{2}mv^2 (v^2 e^{-mv^2/2kT})}{\int_0^\infty v^2e^{-mv^2/2kT}}$$

where $v^2e^{-mv^2/2kT}$ is the $\textbf{speed distribution}$ of the gas molecules. The first method evaluate to $kT/2$, while the second method evaluate to the expected result of $3kT/2$. What is wrong with the first method? Which one should I use in this case? Thank you.

Comment: Consider to use \langle and \rangle to get $\langle$ and $\rangle$, respectively. It then reads $\langle E\rangle$ instead of $<E>$, for example.

Comment: Your equations are missing the differential (presumably $\mathrm{d}v$), which is pretty important in an integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Velocity is a vector with three components. To integrate over the velocity, you need to do a triple integral in three-dimensional velocity space. If you use the first equation, you are only integrating over a single component of the velocity, so you get one third of the expected result. The second equation is the correct one, and the factor of $v^2$ comes from the surface area of a sphere in velocity space. (It's really a $4 \pi v^2$, but the $4\pi$ cancels with the same factor in the partition function.) In the second equation, we have already integrated over all possible directions of the velocity vector, so we are left with an integral over the magnitude of the velocity (the speed).